# How to lookup element in AWS response with lxml (namespace issue?)

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to use lxml to read a response from the AWS REST API but not having any luck. I can easily parse the response and print it, but none of the `find` or `xpath` functions find anything.  For example, take this document fragment:

```
<DistributionConfig xmlns="http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-11-11/">
  <CallerReference>e6d6909d-f1ed-47f1-83d9-290acf10f324</CallerReference>
  <Aliases>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Items>
```

And this code:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.XML( ... )
node = root.find( 'Quantity' )
```

`node` is always `None`. I've tried a variety of xpaths like `//Quanity`, `.//Quantity`, and also the `xpath` function, but can't find anything.

How do I use this library on this type of document?

Comment: `find` does not descend here. Perhaps `root.find('Aliases/Quantity')` would do?

Comment: You can also wildcard `Aliases` (use `root.find('*/Quantity')`; I think it should work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you will need to supply the namespace of the element as well:

```
>>> root.find('.//aws:Quantity', namespaces={'aws': 'http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-11-11/'})
<Element {http://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/doc/2013-11-11/}Quantity at 0xb6c16aa4>
```

Comment: Okay, that seems to work. Do you know if there is anyway to specify a `namespaces` map for the whole document? I don't wish to have to type that part for every call.

Comment: Well, the value for the `namespaces` parameter in the `root.filter` call is just a dictionary. You can assign that dictionary to a variable and reuse it (`root.find('...', namespaces=nsdict)`).